# How I should point to my resource.xml when I am setting up arquillian with tomee?

Tags: jboss-arquillian, apache-tomee, glassfish-embedded

With glassfish-embedded server I used the following line in arquillian.xml to specify my resource.xml

arquillian.xml

```
   <container qualifier="glassfish-embedded" >
    <configuration>
        <property name="resourcesXml">
            src/test/resources-glassfish-embedded/glassfish-resources.xml
        </property>
    </configuration>
</container>
```

glassfish-resources.xml

```
<resources>
<jdbc-resource pool-name="ArquillianEmbeddedDerbyPool"
    jndi-name="jdbc/arquillian"/>
<jdbc-connection-pool name="ArquillianEmbeddedDerbyPool"
    res-type="javax.sql.DataSource"
    datasource-classname="org.apache.derby.jdbc.EmbeddedDataSource"
    is-isolation-level-guaranteed="false">
    <property name="databaseName" value="target/databases/derby"/>
    <property name="createDatabase" value="create"/>
</jdbc-connection-pool>
</resources>
```

Now I am trying to use tomee and I couldn't connect to my database, because I cannot point out to my resource.xml in the same way which I used with glassfish.

here is the warning which indicate that the resourcesXml property is not supported with Tomee (in Arquillian.xml)

```
WARNING: Configuration contain properties not supported by the backing object org.apache.openejb.arquillian.embedded.EmbeddedTomEEConfiguration
Unused property entries: {resourcesXml=
            src/test/resources-glassfish-embedded/glassfish-resources.xml
        }
```

I want to know the alternative setting for specifying resources in tomee with arquillian.I will appreciate any help in this regards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

finally I managed to setup Arquillian with CDI, hibernate, embeded in memory H2 database on TomEE. Actually we don't need any resource.xml. all we need is a beans.xml for CDI and persistence.xml for defining dataSource and persistence unit. Here is My shrinkWrap with my setting files for TomEE , H2, CDI and Hibernate.

my test class with ShrinkWrap

```
import org.apache.openejb.assembler.classic.AppInfo;
import org.apache.openejb.assembler.classic.Assembler;
import org.apache.openejb.assembler.classic.ReloadableEntityManagerFactory;
import org.apache.openejb.jee.jba.cmp.AddColumnTemplate;
import org.apache.openejb.loader.SystemInstance;
import org.apache.openejb.spi.ContainerSystem;
import org.apache.ziplock.JarLocation;
import org.jboss.arquillian.container.test.api.Deployment;
import org.jboss.arquillian.junit.Arquillian;
import org.jboss.shrinkwrap.api.ArchivePaths;
import org.jboss.shrinkwrap.api.ShrinkWrap;
import org.jboss.shrinkwrap.api.asset.EmptyAsset;
import org.jboss.shrinkwrap.api.asset.StringAsset;
import org.jboss.shrinkwrap.api.spec.WebArchive;
import org.jboss.shrinkwrap.resolver.api.ResolutionException;
import org.jboss.shrinkwrap.resolver.api.maven.Maven;
import org.jboss.shrinkwrap.resolver.api.maven.ScopeType;
import org.jboss.shrinkwrap.resolver.api.maven.strategy.AcceptScopesStrategy;
import org.junit.After;
import org.junit.Assert;
import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;

import se.raindance.yashar.Game;

import javax.inject.Inject;
import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory;
import javax.persistence.PersistenceContext;
import javax.persistence.PersistenceContextType;
import javax.persistence.PersistenceUnit;
import javax.transaction.UserTransaction;

import java.io.File;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Set;

import static org.junit.Assert.assertNotNull;
import static org.junit.Assert.assertTrue;

@RunWith(Arquillian.class)
public class HibernateTest {
    @Deployment
    public static WebArchive war() {
        File[] hibernate;
        try { // try offline first since it is generally faster
            hibernate = Maven.resolver()
                    .offline(true)
                    .loadPomFromFile("src/test/resources/hibernate-pom.xml")
                    .importRuntimeAndTestDependencies(new AcceptScopesStrategy(ScopeType.COMPILE, ScopeType.RUNTIME))
                    .asFile();
        } catch (ResolutionException re) { // try on central
            hibernate = Maven.resolver()
                    .loadPomFromFile("src/test/resources/hibernate-pom.xml")
                    .importRuntimeAndTestDependencies(new AcceptScopesStrategy(ScopeType.COMPILE, ScopeType.RUNTIME))
                    .asFile();
        }

        WebArchive webArchive =  ShrinkWrap.create(WebArchive.class, "hibernate-app.war")
                  .addAsWebInfResource("test-persistence.xml", "classes/META-INF/persistence.xml")   
                  .addAsWebInfResource(EmptyAsset.INSTANCE, "classes/META-INF/beans.xml")
                .addAsLibraries(hibernate)
                .addAsLibraries(JarLocation.jarLocation(ResolutionException.class))
                .addClasses(Game.class)
                .addAsLibraries(JarLocation.jarLocation(org.jboss.shrinkwrap.resolver.api.maven.filter.MavenResolutionFilter.class));


        System.out.println(webArchive.toString(true));
        return webArchive;
    }

    private static final String[] GAME_TITLES = {
        "Super Mario Brothers",
        "Mario Kart",
        "F-Zero"
    };

    @PersistenceContext(unitName = "yasharUnit")
    EntityManager em;           

    @Inject
    UserTransaction utx;

    @Before
    public void preparePersistenceTest() throws Exception {
        clearData();
        insertData();
        startTransaction();
    }

    private void clearData() throws Exception {
        utx.begin();
        em.joinTransaction();
        System.out.println("Dumping old records...");
        em.createQuery("delete from Game").executeUpdate();
        utx.commit();
    }

    private void insertData() throws Exception {
        utx.begin();
        em.joinTransaction();
        System.out.println("Inserting records...");
        for (String title : GAME_TITLES) {
            Game game = new Game(title);
            em.persist(game);
        }
        utx.commit();
        em.clear();
    }

    private void startTransaction() throws Exception {
        utx.begin();
        em.joinTransaction();
    }

    @After
    public void commitTransaction() throws Exception {
        utx.commit();
    }

    @Test
    public void shouldFindAllGamesUsingJpqlQuery() throws Exception {
        // given
        String fetchingAllGamesInJpql = "select g from Game g order by g.id";

        // when
        System.out.println("Selecting (using JPQL)...");
        List<Game> games = em.createQuery(fetchingAllGamesInJpql, Game.class).getResultList();

        // then
        System.out.println("Found " + games.size() + " games (using JPQL):");
        assertContainsAllGames(games);
    }


    private static void assertContainsAllGames(Collection<Game> retrievedGames) {
        Assert.assertEquals(GAME_TITLES.length, retrievedGames.size());
        final Set<String> retrievedGameTitles = new HashSet<String>();
        for (Game game : retrievedGames) {
            System.out.println("* " + game);
            retrievedGameTitles.add(game.getTitle());
        }
        Assert.assertTrue(retrievedGameTitles.containsAll(Arrays.asList(GAME_TITLES)));
    }
}
```

hibernate-pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>org.apache.openejb.arquillian.tests</groupId>
  <version>1.0.0</version>
  <artifactId>codi-deps</artifactId>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
      <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
      <version>4.1.6.Final</version>
      <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
          <groupId>org.hibernate.javax.persistence</groupId>
          <artifactId>hibernate-jpa-2.0-api</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
        <exclusion>
          <groupId>org.jboss.spec.javax.transaction</groupId>
          <artifactId>jboss-transaction-api_1.1_spec</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
        <exclusion>
          <groupId>org.javassist</groupId>
          <artifactId>javassist</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
      </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
      <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
      <version>4.3.0.Final</version>
  <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
          <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
          <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
      </exclusions>
    </dependency>

  </dependencies>
</project>
```

persistence.xml

```
<persistence xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd"
    version="2.0">
    <persistence-unit name="yasharUnit" transaction-type="JTA">
     <jta-data-source>yasharDataSource</jta-data-source>
     <non-jta-data-source>yasharUnmanagedDataSource</non-jta-data-source>
        <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>

        <class>se.raindance.yashar.Game</class>
        <properties>
            <property name="hibernate.connection.username" value="sa" />
            <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class" value="org.h2.Driver" />
            <property name="hibernate.connection.password" value="" />
            <property name="hibernate.connection.url" value="jdbc:h2:~/test;AUTO_SERVER=TRUE" />
            <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect" />
            <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true" />
            <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="create-drop" />

            <property name="openjpa.jdbc.SynchronizeMappings" value="buildSchema(ForeignKeys=true)"/>
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

and finally our sample Game Entity

```
import java.io.Serializable;

import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.validation.constraints.NotNull;
import javax.validation.constraints.Size;

/**
 * @author Yashar Bizhanzadeh
 *
 */

@Entity
public class Game implements Serializable {
    private Long id;
    private String title;

    public Game() {}

    public Game(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }

    @Id @GeneratedValue
    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    @NotNull
    @Size(min = 3, max = 50)
    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }

    public void setTitle(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Game@" + hashCode() +
            "[id = " + id + "; title = " + title + "]";
    }
}
```

arquillian.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<arquillian xmlns="http://jboss.org/schema/arquillian"
            xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
            xsi:schemaLocation="http://jboss.org/schema/arquillian http://jboss.org/schema/arquillian/arquillian_1_0.xsd">

  <container qualifier="tomee-embedded" default="true">
    <configuration>
      <property name="httpPort">-1</property>
      <property name="stopPort">-1</property>
      <property name="dir">target/tomee-embedded</property>
      <property name="appWorkingDir">target/arquillian-embedded-working-dir</property>
      <property name="portRange">20001-30000</property>

    </configuration>
  </container>
  </arquillian>
```

and an empty beans.xml.

Comment: here is the bunch of TomEE, Arquillian examples,   http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/tomee/tomee/tags/tomee-1.5.2/arquillian/